# Remove a bullet character in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider:

```
users_df['LASTNAME_TEST'] = users_df['LASTNAME'].replace(u'•','')

for item in users_df['LASTNAME_TEST']:
    if u'•' in item:
        print('yay')
```

I'm trying to remove the special bullet character in this column and using *replace*. This is still returning `yay` in the result. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `replace(u'•','', regex=True)` ?

Comment: thank you! that was it

Answer (score 0):

Per [SeaBean's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69816324/remove-bullet-character-in-pandas-colum#comment123410756_69816324), add `regex=True` to the call to `.replace()`:

```py
users_df['LASTNAME_TEST'] = users_df['LASTNAME'].replace(u'•', '', regex=True)
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```